# Глава и голова - в чём разница?

Tags: значение-слов

Знаю, что "глава" и "голова" могут быть одним и тем же, но слова-то разные, стало быть и понятия должны быть разными. Видите ли разницу? 
Не надо про "устаревшее" и про "высокое", потому что это не объясняет толкования слов. Тем более "глава книги" не может быть "головой книги". 
Примеры. 
"Городской голова" - "голова" используется вместо "глава". 
"Склонить главу" - "глава" используется вместо "голова". 
"Глава повес, трибун трактирный" - где здесь высокое, когда речь о главном? 
 
"Головной дозор", "главный", "златоглавый" и "златоголовый".  
В чём разница?

Comment: Вы можете обратиться к словарям.

Answer (score 1):

Глава - это должность в структуре какой либо организации, которая предусмотрена планом этой организации.
Голова - это сложившееся положение человека, когда его все слушаются, под влиянием его авторитета. Это по аналогии с телом человека, где тело подчиняется голове.

Например:
Глава города и голова города вовсе не обязательно один человек. Глава города назначается правительством, а голова города получается естественным образом.
Склонить главу о голове тела человека говорить неправильно. Хотя не исключаю что раньше так говорили, когда язык был другим. Так же и в других ваших примерах "глава повес" и "городоской голова" скорее всего имеются ввиду устаревшие значения.

Comment: "Голова - это сложившееся...", типа: "ну, ты и голова!" (умный, сообразительный)? Тогда это жаргон.